# Django, open a file in template with \n

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'd like to display the content of a file `file1` link to one of my object `object1`.

In my view, I added `object1` to the context.
In my django template, I used:

```
<html> [...]
{{ object1.file1.read }}
[...]
</html>
```

This works perfectly but let's say  my file is like this:

```
Lorem ipsum \n
\n
This is a pretty stupid SO question, sorry\n
foo bar
```

It's rendered in only one line. `\n` are not interpreted. What should I do? Is there some tag/filter/blackmagic I could add to do so? Moreover, what kind of characters will be eluded using {{ file.read }} to be less specific ?

Cheers guyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `linebreaksbr` filter like this:

```
{{ object1.file1.read|linebreaksbr }}
```

Comment: Annnnnnd.... That's it! THanks! I was struggling with the doc to find that word again. Great! Cheers!